Kotlin Coroutine: How to do continuous trySend with callbackflow?
I am trying to utilize Kotlin Coroutine for background process with an external API.

class SampleRepoImpl(private val readerApi: ReaderApi) : SampleRepo {

   override fun startReader() = callbackFlow {

      readerApi.searchCard(object : OnSearchCardListener {
      
         override fun onCardDetect() {
             trySend(ReaderState.Detect)
             close()
         }
       
         override fun onCardFound() {
             trySend(ReaderState.Found)
             close()
         }

         override fun onFinish() {
             trySend(ReaderState.Close)
             close()
         }

      })

      awaitClose()

   }

}


The callback flow will be onCardDetect then onCardFound, the problem in this code is after calling close() in onCardDetect then callbackFlow also ends as a whole thus not capturing the whole callback states. Is there a way to keep it alive and terminate it if the viewModelScope cancel it or on specific callback for example in onFinish?

Why are you close()-ing your flow in onDetect then?

@Pawel I thought it is required to be able to collect each trySend? It's not?!

Why would it? Example provided in the docs doesn't do this: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html . Also, I suggest using trySendBlocking or at least check the result of sending. Above code may silently ignore items. trySend, as its names suggests, only tries sending and it may fail doing so.

@broot thanks, I thought that in order to collect each trySend I need to call close(). Will use trySendBlocking as well, just want to verify if my understanding is correct that using trySend may not emit anything if has some failure while trySendBlocking will inform use and throw some exception?

trySend returns false if it fails to send - this happens when flow collector is busy and cannot handle the value immediately. Consider adding a .buffer() to your flow., that way trySend() will never fail.

trySendBlocking should generally almost always succeed, it waits to succeed. According to docs, the only potential reason is that the channel is closed, which should never happen. I guess you can treat this case as a code bug and simply throw: trySendBlocking(...).getOrThrow(). trySend is much different - it simply checks if can send right now and if not, it just gives up. It is very probable we get failures from it, just because we produce items quickly.

Or we can use an infinite buffer and then trySend should be similar to trySendBlocking. Depending on our case.

You should only call close() when you actually want the flow to finish. If you don't, then don't call it. From what I gather you should remove close() from onCardDetect and onCardFound.
You can keep the close() in onFinish if you can guarantee that no further callbacks are called for OnSearchCardListener after that.
